# Twitter search returns only 100 tweets

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am using the twitter gem (https://github.com/sferik/twitter) and I tried searching and I am getting only 100 results.

How do I get more tweets?

```
Twitter.search("google",:since=>'2013-03-5',:include_entities=>false,:count=>1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's search API only lets you get a maximum of 100 search results per request, per the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) (see the **count** description).

You may be able to make multiple search requests and pass the `:max_id` option to provide a search result offset, see the same API doc page for details or the Twitter gem [`search`](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API/Search#search-instance_method) method documentation.